# Angular2 issue accessing property of an object

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object named "User" and each user has companies array of type "Company".

I'm trying to make changes on the companies array but I can't access the companies property, this is the error that I get:

```
authentication.service.ts (72,25): Property 'companies' does not exist on type 'User'.)
```

this is my User class:

```
import { Company } from './company';

export class User {
    constructor(
        public email:string,
        public name:string,
        public token:string,
        public companies: Company[]
    ){
}
```

and this is my company class:

```
export class Company {
    constructor(
        public id:number,
        public name:string,
        public is_active:boolean
    ){}
}
```

I first set the user on the AuthService below and then I'm getting the error while i using the "updateCompany" function

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../_models/user";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private user: User;

  constructor(private http: Http,private router:Router) {
    // set token if saved in local storage
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    this.user = currentUser;
  }

    login(email:string,password:string): Observable<boolean> {
        const body = JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password });
        const headers = new Headers({
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        });

        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/signin",body,{headers:headers})
            .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a token in the response
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if(token){

                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response.json()));

                    // set user object
                    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
                //return response.json();
            }
          );
    }

    getUser(){
        return this.user;
    }

    updateCompany(company_id){
        console.log(this.user.companies);
    }

}
```

update:
this is how i call the updateCompany:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../../_services/index';
import { User } from "../../../../_models/user";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private user: User;

  constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authenticationService.getUser();
  }

  changeCompany(company_id){
    this.authenticationService.updateCompany(company_id);
  }

  onLogout(){
    this.authenticationService.logout();
  }
}
```

Comment: does you service returns companies list when `signin` API is called?

Comment: Can we see the part, where updateCompany is actually called? I think your user might not have finished loading when you call updateCompany

Comment: @Neutrosider I edit the question and added the HeaderComponent which is calling the function

Comment: @IlanFinkel reply for my comment

Comment: if i just write console.log(this.user) in the updateCompany function it works fine i have all the data there

Comment: are you available in teamviewer???

Comment: i return the same structure as the User object: name,email,token and companies array

Comment: SO you are saying in update companies function when you console.log (this.user) companies exist on the user but when you try to access this.companies.user then it shows you an error?

Comment: @IlanFinkel could it be, that you need in instantiate the user?
do you get this error when trying to build?
Is there a reason your User, and Company types are classes, instead of interfaces?

Comment: when i running console.log(this.user) in the updateCompany function it have this output: Object {email: "myemail@gmail.com", name: "myname", token: "eyJ0e", companies: Array(2)}

Comment: UPDATE: i change the models into interfaces and i still have the same error

Comment: @IlanFinkel Could reproduce the issue in a plunker. I tried and simulated your code, and it worked fine for me...